# How to load value of an ENUM from XML file?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and trying to parse an XML file with objects having ENUM parameters as well. One of the ENUMs have a value as well. And at parsing I get error message (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.codecool.enums.AreaToUse.4).

the ENUM is

```
public enum AreaToUse {
    TRAFICH(6),
    TRAFICM(5),
    HOMEH(4),
    HOMEL(3);

    private final int qualified;

    AreaToUse(int qualified) {
        this.qualified = qualified;
    }

    public int getQualified() {
        return qualified;
    }
}
```

the xml

```
<Lumber name="pineLong" producer="Nati" load="M" value="17.3"
 qualified="4" length="3200" width="350" thickness="22"
 species="pine"/>
```

and the parsing

```
for (int i = 0; i < lumbers.getLength(); i++) {
    current = (Element) lumbers.item(i);
    result.add(new Lumber(current.getAttribute("name"),
                      current.getAttribute("producer"),
                      Load.valueOf(current.getAttribute("load")),
                 Double.parseDouble(current.getAttribute("value")),
              AreaToUse.valueOf(current.getAttribute("qualified")),
                  Integer.parseInt(current.getAttribute("length")),
                Integer.parseInt(current.getAttribute("width")),
               Integer.parseInt(current.getAttribute("thickness")),
                current.getAttribute("species")));
}
```

my expected outcome is

pineLong, Nati, M, 17.3, 4, 3200, 350, 22, pine

actual return is
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.codecool.enums.AreaToUse.4

Comment: Your enum value is called `HOMEH`, not `4`. So either you must change your XML (`qualified="HOMEH"`) or you must write some code inside your enum to map from the integer value to the enum value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a utility method like `valueOfInt` in `ENUM AreaToUse`  which will convert your `qualified int` to a `corresponding ENUM` value.

```
public static AreaToUse valueOfInt(int i) {
    return Arrays.stream(AreaToUse.values())
            .filter(e -> e.getQualified() == i)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
}
```

And use it like:

```
AreaToUse.valueOfInt(current.getAttribute("qualified"))
```

If your `current.getAttribute("qualified")` returns a String then parse it to integer.

```
AreaToUse.valueOfInt(Integer.parseInt(current.getAttribute("qualified")))
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to write a method which returns the right `Enum` by the `qualified` value because `valueOf` searches an `Enum` by the given `String`. That is why you get the message `No enum constant com.codecool.enums.AreaToUse.4`. You have no `AreaToUse` called `4`.

Try this:

```java
public enum AreaToUse {
    ...
    public static AreaToUse byQualified(int qualified) {
        AreaToUse returnValue = null;
        for(AreaToUse areaToUse : values()) {
            if(areaToUse.getQualified() == qualified) {
                returnValue = areaToUse;
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Instead I would recommend to create a map which maps qualified value to the area enum:

```java
public enum AreaToUse {

    private static final Map<Integer, AreaToUse> MAPPING = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        for(AreaToUse areaToUse : values()) {
            MAPPING.put(areaToUse.getQualified(), areaToUse);
        }
    }
    public static AreaToUse byQualified(int qualified) {
        return MAPPING.get(qualified);
    }
}
```